# Kotlin CDI Interceptor Not Being Called

Tags: java, kotlin, cdi, interceptor

I'm trying to learn Kotlin by porting over some existing Java code to see the differences.  I'm trying to write a simple CDI `Interceptor` that will allow me to log the start and end of an annotated method.  My interceptor and annotation look like this:

```
import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding

@InterceptorBinding
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS, AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Logged {

}



import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext

@Interceptor
@Logged
class LoggingInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    fun logFunctionDetails(context: InvocationContext): Any  {
        print("logFunctionDetails - start")

        // TODO Implement method

        print("logFunctionDetails - end")
        return context.proceed()
    }
}
```

I've also got a simple JAX-RS endpoint annotated with @Logged.  It looks like this:

```
@Path("/healthCheck")
@Stateless
@Logged
open class HealthCheckRS : AbstractRestService() {

    @Path("/")
    @GET
    @POST
    @PUT
    @DELETE
    @HEAD
    @OPTIONS
    @Logged
    open fun healthCheck(): String {
        return "" + System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see my `LoggingInterceptor` function called, but it is completely bypassing the interceptor altogether.  Is there something more that I need to do in order to get this working in Kotlin?  I have similar code that works in Java with no problem.

Comment: A quick check - is your interceptor enabled? I see no `@Priority` on your interceptor (and you didn't mention `beans.xml`).

Comment: Duh.  I was so focused on the Kotlin aspect that I completely missed the @Priority annotation.  Thanks for bringing me back to reality!

Comment: you may want to supply this comment as an answer instead and accept it. Otherwise it will forever be an unanswered question ;-) and you both can profit from it and maybe also someone else... ;-)

Comment: As soon as one of you posts the comment as answer, I will happily delete the answer placeholder again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [Siliarus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5342297/siliarus): Is your interceptor enabled? I see no `@Priority` on your interceptor (and you didn't mention `beans.xml`).

*This answer is rather a placeholder so that this question is not listed on the unanswered questions anymore. In fact the comment was the solution.*